# Create group and show sum on pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Sample code

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dayOfMonth = np.random.randint(low =1, high =32, size=(50))
dayOfWeek = np.random.randint(low =1, high =6, size=(50))
dayOfWork = np.random.randint(low =1, high =22, size=(50))
minute = np.random.randint(low =1, high =61, size=(50))

data = {'DayOfWeek' : dayOfWeek,
        'DayOfWork' : dayOfWork,
        'Minute' : minute}

df = pd.DataFrame (data)

sns.set_style("whitegrid");

sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="DayOfWeek", height=10) \
   .map(plt.scatter, "DayOfWork","Minute") \
   .add_legend();
plt.xticks(range(0,22,1))
plt.yticks(range(0,61,10))

plt.show();
```

Current plot.
[image]

Expected plot.
[image]

Is this expectation is possible?
I'm new in this field, so pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_start_end_point(df, x_range, cluster_size):
    start_x = 0
    start_y = 0
    end_x = -1
    end_y = -1
    x_points = []
    y_points = []
    x_group = []
    y_group = []
    groups_sum = []
    group_sum = 0
    for i in x_range:
        temp = df[df['DayOfWork'] == i]
        if i%cluster_size == 1:
            x_group.append(i)
            y_group.append(0)
        if len(temp) != 0:
            group_sum +=temp['Minute'].sum()
            x_group.append(i)
            y_group.append(temp['Minute'].iloc[-1])
        if (i%cluster_size == 0 or i == x_range.stop) and i !=0:
            x_group.append(i)
            y_group.append(0)
            x_points.append(x_group.copy())
            y_points.append(y_group.copy())
            groups_sum.append(group_sum)
            x_group.clear()
            y_group.clear()
            group_sum = 0
            
    return x_points, y_points, groups_sum

dayOfWeek = np.random.randint(low =1, high =6, size=(50))
dayOfWork = np.random.randint(low =1, high =22, size=(50))
minute = np.random.randint(low =1, high =61, size=(50))

data = {'DayOfWeek' : dayOfWeek,
        'DayOfWork' : dayOfWork,
        'Minute' : minute}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x_points,y_points, groups_sum = get_start_end_point(df.sort_values(["DayOfWork", "Minute"]).reset_index(drop=True),range(0,22),3)

sns.set_style("whitegrid");

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xticks(range(0,22,1))
ax.set_yticks(range(0,61,10))

for i in range(0, len(x_points)):
    ax.plot(x_points[i], y_points[i],'b--',lw = 1)
    ax.fill_between(x_points[i], y_points[i], color='#c9eaff') 

sns_plot = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="DayOfWeek", height=10)
sns_plot.map(ax.scatter, "DayOfWork","Minute")
sns_plot.add_legend()
```

After this, I'm able to create groups and change the background color too.

But when I try to show the plot, It shows in two subplots. Its label, X-axis, and Y-axis name are shown in the second plot.

Also I have the sum of the group, How can I display on top of the group?

[image]